# Microsoft Word Visual Basic for Applications - Find Last Page Break and Delete All Pages Above

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a novice when it comes to Visual Basic for Applications - Microsoft Word. Could you please tell me the programatically correct way to look for the last page break and delete all pages above it.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually inserted page breaks in Word document (via Insert > Page Break) can be identified by searching for `^m`.
This makes it straightforward to remove all pages except the final one.

```
Sub RemovePages()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngPos As Long
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "^m"
        Set rng = .Parent
        Do While .Execute = True
            lngPos = rng.End
            .Execute findText:="", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
            .Text = "^m"
        Loop
        Debug.Print lngPos
    End With
    If lngPos > 0 Then ActiveDocument.Range(0, lngPos + 1).Delete
End Sub
```

[Credit to `Timothy Rylatt`] There is a simple soultion to get the last page break.

```
Sub RemovePages1()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "^m"
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Set rng = .Parent
        If .Execute Then ActiveDocument.Range(0, rng.End + 1).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Finding the last occurrence is much simpler if you set `Forward:=False` as this will work through the document from the end.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt You are absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: @TimothyRylatt the short and sweet answer worked for me. thank you.